# More efficient way to restructure data than UNION every column separately? (Access limitation)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (200 rows * 77 columns) that has to be restructured in a table with 4 columns. Something which should be possible with UNION, but I end up with 75 UNION statements, something msAccess2007 doesn't except. Furthermore it's annoying to construct, even with concatenating the code together in Excel. (If I run my code in two blocks it works fine.)

So is there a way to make the code shorter, so that Access can handle it AND that it would be easier to write?

Example data

```
ID      Var1_1  Var2_1  Var2_2      Var2_3
C2816   45654           5.050551    4.050
B2811           5.98    
C2814   453     1.52        
C2819   4               3.06141     6.8845
B291    53                          2.2
```

What the result should look like

```
ID      ContentGroup Content    Volume
C2816   Var1         Var1_1     45654
C2816   Var2         Var2_2     5.050505051
C2816   Var2         Var2_3     4.05
B2811   Var2         Var2_2     5.98
C2814   Var1         Var1_1     453
C2814   Var2         Var2_1     1.52
```

Example code

```
SELECT [tbl].ID, "Var1" AS ContentGroup, "Var1_1" AS Content, [tbl]![Var1] AS Volume 
FROM tbl 
WHERE ((([tbl]![Var1_1]) Is Not Null)) 
UNION 
SELECT [tbl].ID, "Var2" AS ContentGroup, "Var2_1" AS Content, [tbl]![Var2_1] AS Volume 
FROM tbl 
WHERE ((([tbl]![Var2_1]) Is Not Null)) 
UNION 
SELECT [tbl].ID, "Var2" AS ContentGroup, "Var2_2" AS Content, [tbl]![Var2_2] AS Volume 
FROM tbl 
WHERE ((([tbl]![Var2_2] Is Not Null)) 
UNION 
SELECT [tbl].ID, "Var" AS ContentGroup, "Var2_3" AS Content, [tbl]![Var2_3] AS Volume 
FROM tbl 
...
```

I tried to SELECT * FROM (all the unions) WHERE (Content Is Not Null); This not a solution, not working and hardly easier to construct.

I'm thinking in the direction of selecting columns that start with Var, taking the first 4 characters of the varname AS ContentGroup, the varname AS Content, but I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Are you going to do this once or is it a repeatable process?

Comment: It's a one time thing, the data was stored in the wrong way. But it's not the first time I come across this type of restructuring.

Comment: If you are stuck with Access then it is the only way. In MS SQL Server you would use UNPIVOT

Comment: I solved it Excel with the answer of @Brad, but good to know that a function like UNPIVOT exists and can do similar, even if it's in a different software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing this once you can do this. Put your data in Excel (xlsx, not xls).

I wrote this procedure a while back to unpivot data in Excel because I was getting tons of data like this. What this function will do is the same as when you make multiple consolidation ranges (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>), then double click on the Grand Total cell in the bottom right.

I have an extra bit in there that will, split on "|" and make new columns because sometimes I have many things uniquely IDing records (Site and Date..)

When you run it you'll be prompted to select the range (all your data) then hit enter. It will turn those data into a pivot table, and "show Detail" for the grant total for you. It will then delete the pivot table sheet and leave you with fresh, normalized data.

When it looks good, import it back into access. You can use the `left` function to turn `Var1_1` --> `Var1`

Given your data this is the result I get

```
Row Column  Value
B2811   Var1_1  5.98
B2811   Var2_1  
B2811   Var2_2  
B2811   Var2_3  
B291    Var1_1  53
B291    Var2_1  2.2
B291    Var2_2  
B291    Var2_3  
C2814   Var1_1  453
C2814   Var2_1  1.52
C2814   Var2_2  
C2814   Var2_3  
C2816   Var1_1  45654
C2816   Var2_1  5.050551
C2816   Var2_2  4.05
C2816   Var2_3  
C2819   Var1_1  4
C2819   Var2_1  3.06141
C2819   Var2_2  6.8845
C2819   Var2_3
```

.

```
Sub UnpivotData()
    Dim OBJECT_REQUIRED_ERROR As Integer, UNABLE_TO_SHOW_DETAIL_ERROR As Integer
    OBJECT_REQUIRED_ERROR = 424
    UNABLE_TO_SHOW_DETAIL_ERROR = 1004

    Dim sourceRange As Range, sourceSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sourceRange = Application.InputBox("Select cell(s)", Type:=8, Title:="Select range to unpivot...")
    If Err.Number = OBJECT_REQUIRED_ERROR Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim fullRangeAddress As String
    fullRangeAddress = "'" & sourceRange.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & sourceRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, external:=False)

    Dim pvtchache  As PivotCache, newPivotTable As PivotTable
    Set pvtchache = sourceRange.Worksheet.Parent.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:=Array(fullRangeAddress), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)
    Set newPivotTable = pvtchache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)            'TableName:="PivotTable2",

    Dim pivotWorksheet As Worksheet, numberOfNewColumns As Integer, detailWorksheet As Worksheet

    Set pivotWorksheet = ActiveSheet  'the last function will make this the active worksheet as default behavior
    On Error Resume Next
    pivotWorksheet.Cells(newPivotTable.RowRange.Rows.Count + 1, newPivotTable.ColumnRange.Columns.Count + 1).ShowDetail = True    'go to the bottom right corner (grand grand total)
    If Err.Number = UNABLE_TO_SHOW_DETAIL_ERROR Then
        MsgBox "Could not find the Grand Total cell. You'll have to double click it yourself to finish."
    End If

    Set detailWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    numberOfNewColumns = Len(detailWorksheet.Range("A2")) - Len(Replace(detailWorksheet.Range("A2"), "|", ""))

    Dim i As Integer
    Do While i < numberOfNewColumns
        detailWorksheet.Columns(2).Insert
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Dim txtToColsRange As Range
    With detailWorksheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Range("A1") = sourceRange.Cells(1, 1)
        Set txtToColsRange = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    End With
    txtToColsRange.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    detailWorksheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    pivotWorksheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Multiple consolidation ranges does the trick. I tried the VBA code, but it ran into an error. Since it's a one time thing, for the moment,  I'll use the `code`Alt + d,p`code` option. But definitely worth investing in that code if it becomes a more frequent issue.
Thanks!

Comment: @LaurensP cool, np. Yeah the code is catered to how I have data given to me and I use it a lot, but maybe your data look slightly different. Glad it worked out for you though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a real shortcut here.

1. You can break it up int0 several selects rather than one with all the unions and insert into the new table structure in pieces rather than all at once. I'd prefer individual insert..select rather than one with all the unions in this case.
2. If for some reason you want all the unions you could export to SQL Server and do you manipulations and import back. SQL Server doesn't have a UNION limit.
3. You could do this with a horrific CASE construction, but I wouldn't.
4. In SQL Server you could construct and execute dynamic sql in a cursor, but this would be no better than using excel to construct the statements if it wasn't an often repeatable process.

Comment: Apparently you can add UNPIVOT to your list of options, if you're using SQL Server.